# Convert decimal number into excel alphabet

Tags: labview

My concern is to convert number into alphabet in excel column like this in Labview.

[image]

Is there any easy way to do this?

Edit

The mapping is like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found any direct way to achieve exactly what you want, but this algorithm should suffice.
[image]

Comment: Converting to base 26 as you do is correct. The spaces (0x00) are coming from the type cast of an Int32 to a (U8) string. A typecast is not what you want here; it flattens the input to a bytestream, then unflattens the bytestream based on the target type. Explicitly convert the I32 to a U8, then use Byte Array to String to get the string. The reversal is needed because base conversion is done right-to-left starting at the 1's.